# Nonlinear differential equation with unknown parameter and integral form boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, parameters

I'm trying to solve numerically a non-linear problem in order to determine the velocity field ($U$) and the film thickness ($h$) of a non-Newtonian fluid over an inclined plane. The equations are,

$$\Biggl(I+(1-I)\Biggl[1+\Biggl(L\frac{dU(y)}{dy}\Biggl)^2\Biggl]^{(n- 
1)/2}\Biggl)\frac{dU(y)}{dy}= -y\,$$

with the boundary conditions,

$$U(h)=0\,$$
$$\int_0^h U(y)dy = 1\,$$

These equation are dimensionless with domain of $y \in [0,h]$. The parameters $I,L $ and $n$ are known. I tried to overcome the difficulty of an unknown domain choosing the transformation $z=\dfrac{y}{h}$. With this transformation the domain $y \in [0,h]$ becomes $z \in [0,1]$. Using $\dfrac{dz}{dy}=\dfrac{1}{h}$ the equations become,

$$\Biggl(I+(1-I)\Biggl[1+\Biggl(\frac{L}{h}\frac{dU(z)}{dz}\Biggl)^2\Biggl]^{(n-1)/2}\Biggl)\frac{1}{h}\frac{dU(z)}{dz}= -zh\,$$

with the boundary conditions,

$$U(1)=0\,$$
$$\int_0^1 U(z)hdz = 1\,$$

I suppose that (in this new system) $h$ becomes a unknown parameter that I must find together with $U(z)$. Therefore; I'm trying to solve this system numerically with `NDSolve`. I'm following a [hint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691) that I found in the Wolfram documentation in how to handle unknown parameters using `NDSolve` in this way (sadly without any success),

```
i=0.5;
L=0.4;
n=0.5;

diff = (i + (1 - i)*(1 + ((L/h[z])*(f'[z]))^2)^((n - 1)/2))*(1/h[z])*
    f'[z] == -(z*h[z])

sol = NDSolve[{diff, h'[z] == 0, f[1] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[NIntegrate[f[z]*h[z],z, 0, 1}] == 1,"StopIntegration"]}, {f, h}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

I believe that my problem is how to implement the integral boundary properly using `NDSolve`. Any help or suggestion will be much appreciated. Thank you for your attention.

PS: Reference to the original [article](https://doi.org/10.1115/1.2742737) that I found this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be solved as follows.  First, solve `diff` with `h[z]` treated as a parameter and the constants as listed in the queston to obtain an explicit expression for `f'[z]`.

```
diff /. {h[z] -> h, n -> 1/2, i -> 1/2, L -> 2/5}
(* (f'[z] (1/2 + 1/(2 (1 + (4 f'[z]^2)/(25 h^2))^(1/4))))/h == -h z *)
Simplify[(h # - i f'[z]) & /@ %];
solf = Equal @@ Simplify[Solve[#^4 & /@ %, f'[z], Reals], z > 0][[2, 1]]
(* (f'[z] == Root[100 h^10 z^4 + 200 h^8 z^3 #1 + (150 h^6 z^2 + 16 h^8 z^4) #1^2 + 
   (50 h^4 z + 32 h^6 z^3) #1^3 + 24 h^4 z^2 #1^4 + 8 h^2 z #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2] *)
```

At this point, the first order ODE could be solved for `f` as a function of `h` by means of `ParametricNDSolve`, the solution integrated over {z, 0, 1}, and `FindRoot` used to vary `h` until the integral equals `1/h`.  However, it is easier to add an auxiliary dependent variable, `g[z]`,

```
g'[z] == h f[z]
```

which is equal to the integral over `h f[z]`, if `g[0] == 0`.

```
 solp = ParametricNDSolveValue[{solf, g'[z] == h f[z], f[1] == 0, g[0] == 0}, 
    {g, f}, {z, 0, 1}, {h}];
```

The integral now can be plotted as a function  of `h`.

```
Plot[First[solp[h]][1], {h, .1, 2}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {h, g[1]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

The desired value of `h` is determined by

```
solh = h /. FindRoot[First[solp[h]][1] == 1, {h, 1}, Evaluated -> False]
(* 1.43127 *)
```

and `f[z]` plotted.

```
Plot[Last[solp[solh]][z], {z, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {z, f}, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

**Addendum: Alternative Solution Technique**

This problem also can be solved using the method described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691). To do so, replace `h` by `h[z]` and include `h'[z] == 0`.

```
NDSolveValue[{solf /. h -> h[z], g'[z] == h[z] f[z], h'[z] == 0, g[0] == 0, f[1] == 0, 
    g[1] == 1} /. h[z] -> Max[h[z], .1], {f[z], h[1]}, {z, 0, 1}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[1] == 0, g[1] == 1, h[1] == 1}}]
```

Note that `/. h[z] -> Max[h[z], .1]` also is necessary to prevent the search for `h[1]` conducted by `NDSolve` from trying `h[1] == 0`, where diff becomes singular.  I do not understand why this additional precaution should be necessary.  In any case, the code just given reproduces the results in the first part of this answer.

**Addendum: More General Solution**

The two preceding solutions require that `n` be a rational number, so that `diff` can be transformed into a polynomial, preferably of low order, in `f'[z]`.  `NDSolve` also can integrate ODEs that cannot be solved explicitly for the leading derivative by automatically using the `{"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` Method to convert the ODE into a DAE.  Unfortunately, the DAE solver cannot handle boundary value problems, forcing the following approach:  Solve the original equation in the question, for which `f` is a function of `y` and the integral constraint is over the range `{y, 0, h}`, with `h` the value of `y` for `f[y] == 0`.  Then vary `f[0]` until the integral equals `1`.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{diff /. {n -> 1/2, i -> 1/2, L -> 2/5}, g'[y] == f[y], 
    f[0] == f0, g[0] == 0, WhenEvent[f[y] == 0, h = y; "StopIntegration"]}, 
    {g, f}, {y, 0, 10}, {f0}];
sf = FindRoot[First[s[f00]][h] - 1, {f00, 1}, Evaluated -> False];
Through[(s[f00] /. %)[h]]
(* {1., -1.73472*10^-17} *)
h
(* 1.43127 *)
Plot[Evaluate@Through[(s[f00] /. sf)[y]], {y, 0, h}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, "g,f"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

With `y == h z` taken into account, the `y` curve is indistinguishable to the eye from the second plot above.  Note, however, that `h` computed here is about `0.7%` smaller than that computed in the preceding approaches.  This small discrepancy perhaps is due to the difference in integration methods used for ODEs and DAEs.

To test this approach for irrational `n` and strong nonlinearity, repeat the computation with `{n -> Pi, i -> 1/2, L -> 2}` to yield `h = 1.80483` and

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear and helpful answer. If you allow me one more question, I would like to know if your code segment (solg = Equal @@ Simplify[Solve[#^4 & /@ %, f'[z], Reals], z > 0][[2, 1]]) took a few hours to run. Again, thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: @brunopc1  Just a few seconds.  To be sure that I had copied my code correctly to my answer, I copied it from my answer to a new notebook and ran it.  No problem.  By the way, I plan to modify my answer a bit tonight.  Results will not change, but the explanation my be more understandable.

Comment: @brunopc1  Just added an additional approach that works for `n` that are irrational as well as rational numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. About the time problem that I mentioned before, it was a small mistake in my code. Everything is running properly now.